# Is there a function that'll only make this email monitor read an email once?

Tags: python

I'm setting up a monitor system inside a bigger program that will check for an email by a set email address for an email address and link. It currently only looks for the email from an array that contains the emails from a file. However, I also want it to look for the link. Now if both of these are found I want it to send an email to the email found inside the received mail. Furthermore, this program will run constantly read the emails and won't stop when the program has read them.

```py
def sendHotmail(receivingEmail, name):
    email = EmailMessage()

    email['Subject'] = subject
    email['From'] = myEmail
    email['To'] = receivingEmail
    if count == 0:
        email.set_content('Hello {},\nI have attached the link to the servey that you will need to complete\n\n www.google.com'.format(name))
    else:
        email.set_content('Hello {},\nHere is the link to your certificate{}'.format(name, link))

    s = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.live.com', port = 587)
    s.starttls()
    s.login(myEmail, myEmailPass)

    s.send_message(email)
    s.quit()

def monitorHotmail():
    m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap-mail.outlook.com',993)
    m.login(myEmail, myEmailPass)
    print(m.list())
    m.select("Inbox")  # <-- response like ('OK', ['74']) --> total no. of mail in sent folder
    while emailsSent != emailsReceived :
        result, data = m.uid('search', None, "ALL") # search all email and return uids
        if result == 'OK':
            for num in data[0].split():
                result, data = m.uid('fetch', num, '(RFC822)')
                if result == 'OK':
                    email_message = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])    # raw email text including headers
                    sentBy = email_message['From']
                    sentBy = sentBy.split(' ')
                    if sentBy[2] == '<xxxxx@gmail.com>':    
                        if email_message.is_multipart():
                            for payload in email_message.get_payload():
                                message = payload.get_payload()
                                for emailFound in emails:
                                    if emailFound in message:
                                        print(emailFound)
```

Other than printing the emails found in the message forever until the email is deleted or program stopped and it not being finished, it works great.

Comment: Hello, I hope you are doing great!

Can you explain what are: 
- emailsSent
- emailsReceived 

Thank you

Comment: When reading a file it adds up 1 for every email accounted for, which is then used to send an first email. It keeps track so that it can know when it needs to stop monitoring the email address's inbox that sent the first emails. My hope is that every time email receives a message with another email address(which is in an array) it'll add up until the emailSent by the email is = emailsReceived by the email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Search to look only for Unseen emails. The Seen flag will be set once you retrieve the RFC822 body (assuming non-peek), so if your Search only looks for Unseen then you’ll only see each message once.

Comment: Ok this almost worked except it seems to read the email 2 or 3 times as shown when printing what it has found